# Create global custom config field

Tags: admin

To create extra fields in the backend I use the code below in system.xml:

```
...
<fields>
    <websiteType>
        <label>Website type</label>
        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
        <source_model>frontendview/selectType</source_model>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <comment>Please select the type of website, this is used to determine certain frontend values</comment>         
    </websiteType>
</fields>
...
```

Even if I set this:

```
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
```

It's shown als options per storeview.

My question: How can I set this as a GLOBAL option?

Answer (score 1):

Setting these child tags should do the trick:

```
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
```

Take for example the setting for `flat_catalog_category` from `Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml`.
It has the values set as above and the field only appears in the default config view.

Make sure you edit the correct field.
Also make sure the field is not defined in an other `system.xml` file that might override your values when merging the files in a single config.

Comment: Thanks Marius, but is stays the same :-S